# Fyneworks jQuery Star Rating Plugin - half ratings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement a star rating system for articles and found [this](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) nice plugin. I have exchanged the default star.gif with my own stars. Everything works fine if I use a full star rating. As soon as I am trying to use the split star function, the stars are not displayed correctly anymore.

The stars itself have a width of 32px.

[image: stars]

The half stars should be on top of the right side of the full stars.

The following if-clause seems to be responsible for calculating the position:

```
// Prepare division control
if(typeof control.split=='number' && control.split>0){
    var stw = ($.fn.width ? star.width() : 0) || control.starWidth;
    var spi = (control.count % control.split), spw = Math.floor(stw/control.split);
    star
    // restrict star's width and hide overflow (already in CSS)
    .width(spw)
    // move the star left by using a negative margin
    // this is work-around to IE's stupid box model (position:relative doesn't work)
    .find('a').css({ 'margin-left':'-'+ (spi*spw) +'px' })
};
```

it is embedded in a "for-each star" loop. I have debugged this with firebug and the calculation seems to be correct. Each second star should have a left-margin of -16px.
For some reason this is not displayed on the site though.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have to mention that I do not have much experience with JS.

Here is the css:

```
div.rating-cancel, div.star-rating {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 17px;
}

div.rating-cancel, div.rating-cancel a {
    background: url("delete.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 -16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

div.star-rating, div.star-rating a {
    background: url("star.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

div.rating-cancel a, div.star-rating a {
    background-position: 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 32px;
}

div.star-rating-on a {
    background-position: 0 -32px !important;
}

div.star-rating-hover a {
    background-position: 0 -64px;
}

div.star-rating-readonly a {
    cursor: default !important;
}

div.star-rating {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot really tell what went wrong here. First of all the width in this setting had to be adjusted. Then one might want to get rid of the float option and use inline-block on the display instead. That way the following components will be drawn in a new line.

```
div.rating-cancel, div.star-rating {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 32px;
}
```

If I changed this value with firebug nothing happened. I replaced the css with the original file and then just added the changes I needed again and voilá, everything looks nice now.